# Changing background transparency for the jquery plugin called fancybox

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, transparency

I am using fancybox for an image gallery.  I am currently trying to set it so the background box as the image changes is semi transparent.  I figured out how to add opacity to the css, but it also makes the picture semi-transparent.

This is how I changed the css:

```
.fancybox-skin {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    /*background: #f9f9f9;*/
    background: #111111;
    opacity:0.6;
    color: #444;
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
       -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Thank you,

CampSoup1988

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be to only change it for CSS3 browsers by setting an alpha channel background:

```
background: rgba(17,17,17,0.6); /* equals #111111 at 60% opacity */
```

And delete your `opacity: 0.6`. The `opacity` property causes the element and all its children to have opacity and cannot be recovered from.

Comment: I plan on using this site (its a personal database running from localhost) using Opera

Comment: @CampSoup1988--Should work in Opera 10.x and up according to [this site](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/).

Comment: I am sorry for taking so long to accept your suggestion.  I got distracted and forgot I asked this question..